# Linux Kernel Makefile.build strange behavior when building external modules

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, kbuild

I need some `KBuild` implementation details advice related to building of external modules.

`Linux Kernel 5.0.0-32`

Here is my `LKM` Makefile:

```
obj-m += pfsw.o
pfsw-objs := src/init.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

Looking at the implementation of [`scripts/Makefile.build`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/scripts/Makefile.build) and printing the debug output with `-d` option I found that the target of this makefile being executed is [`__build`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/scripts/Makefile.build#L70):

```
__build: $(if $(KBUILD_BUILTIN),$(builtin-target) $(lib-target) $(extra-y)) \
     $(if $(KBUILD_MODULES),$(obj-m) $(modorder-target)) \
     $(subdir-ym) $(always)
    @:
```

Since I'm building External LKM the only prerequisites are `$(obj-m)` and `$(modorder-target)`. I got their values from the database:

```
obj-m := /home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/pfsw.o
modorder-target := /home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/modules.order
```

So to execute `__build` the prerequisite `/home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/pfsw.o` have to be built first. There is the following [`$(obj)/%.o:`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/scripts/Makefile.build#L275) pattern rule defined in `Makefile.build`:

```
$(obj)/%.o: $(src)/%.c $(recordmcount_source) $(objtool_dep) FORCE
    $(call cmd,force_checksrc)
    $(call if_changed_rule,cc_o_c)
```

I added debug output to print the name of the target automatic variable:

```
$(obj)/%.o: $(src)/%.c $(recordmcount_source) $(objtool_dep) FORCE
    @echo "$@"
    $(call cmd,force_checksrc)
    $(call cmd,force_check_kmsg)
    $(call if_changed_rule,cc_o_c)
```

and expected `/home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/pfsw.o` to be printed, but actually `/home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/src/init.o` was printed. 
This looks like some magic...

**QUESTION:** Why is building the target `/home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/pfsw.o` causes building `/home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/src/init.o`? Where does it specified in the code?

I understand that there is the `real-obj-m` variable containing exactly the value, but `grep`ing the code base I did not find it depending on something...

Comment: "Why is building the target `/home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/pfsw.o` causes building `/home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/src/init.o`?" - Eh? Exactly the line `pfsw-objs := src/init.o` tells that `pfsw` module consists from `src/init.o` object.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That's right, but `pfsw-objs := src/init.o` is used to "Replace multi-part objects by their individual parts" as stated in the comments to the source code I referenced further. It results in [`real-obj-m := /home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/src/init.o`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/scripts/Makefile.lib#L57) I did not find used anywhere as targets or prerequisites...

Comment: Hm, searching a string "-objs" in `scripts/Makefile.build` has found this line: `$(call multi_depend, $(multi-used-m), .o, -objs -y -m)`. It smells like exactly this line is responsible for dependency between `pfsw.o` and `init.o`. The macro `multi_depend` is defined in [scripts/Makefile.lib](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/scripts/Makefile.lib#L181).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Very likely to be so, thanks much! I checked the value of `multi-used-m`. It was `multi-used-m := /home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/pfsw.o` connecting it with `/home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/src/init.o`. If you post it as an answer I would accept it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Judging by the `make -d` output this is definitely it.

Comment: No, I don't want to write an answer. I didn't read the KBuild makefiles in a deep manner. My comment was just a hint. Feel free to post your answer and use this hint in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tsyvarev hinted in the comments there is a rule to build `obj-m` from its `-objs`.

When analyzing the behavior I mistakenly considered an implicit pattern rule  to build the `obj-m` which in my case is expanded to `/home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/pfsw.o`. Running the build with `make -p` it is possible to notice the following entry in the output:

```
/home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/pfsw.o: FORCE /home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/src/init.o
#  Implicit rule search has not been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: ''
#  File is an intermediate prerequisite.
#  Last modified 2019-12-18 21:13:48.337755924
#  File has been updated.
#  Successfully updated.
# automatic
# @ := /home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/pfsw.o
# automatic
# % := 
# automatic
# * := 
# automatic
# + := FORCE /home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/src/init.o
# automatic
# | := 
# automatic
# < := FORCE
# automatic
# ^ := FORCE /home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/src/init.o
# automatic
# ? := FORCE /home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/src/init.o
# variable set hash-table stats:
# Load=8/32=25%, Rehash=0, Collisions=13/382=3%
#  recipe to execute (from 'scripts/Makefile.build', line 474):
    $(call if_changed,link_multi-m)
    @{ echo $(@:.o=.ko); echo $(filter %.o,$^); \
       $(cmd_undef_syms); } > $(MODVERDIR)/$(@F:.o=.mod)
```

So there is a not-implicit rule specifying a recipe to build `/home/memyself/lkm/procfs_write_perm/pfsw.o` implying that the implicit rule [`$(obj)/%.o:`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/scripts/Makefile.build#L275) should not be considered for that specific case.

The `make` database entry specified above also contains a line number of the recipe to execute and a file it came from. In this case it is

```
recipe to execute (from 'scripts/Makefile.build', line 474):
```

pointing to the [`scripts/Makefile.build`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/scripts/Makefile.build#L464) entry which in my case is

```
$(multi-used-m): FORCE
    $(call if_changed,link_multi-m) # <------ This is the line the database points to
    @{ echo $(@:.o=.ko); echo $(filter %.o,$^); \
       $(cmd_undef_syms); } > $(MODVERDIR)/$(@F:.o=.mod)
$(call multi_depend, $(multi-used-m), .o, -objs -y -m)
```